# novnc:something went wrong,connection is closed

Tags: python

I can't connect my vm with novnc.

I am playing openstack with two nodes. Now I create a vm and I want to connect it with novnc. I use the command `nova --os-region-name=RegionOne get-vnc-console vm1 novnc` to get the VM1 novnc url. And I use it at the firefox.
But it shows that `something went wrong,connection is closed`:

[image]

I use the `"nova --os-region-name=RegionOne get-vnc-console vm1 novnc` to get vm's novnc url.

I want to connect my vm with noc, but I can't.
It shows that `something went wrong,connection is closed`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, and solved.

You might be able to find follow messages in openstack controller /var/log/nova/nova-novncproxy.log

```
2020-11-13 03:22:36.127 1240 INFO nova.console.websocketproxy [-] WebSocket server settings:
2020-11-13 03:22:36.132 1240 INFO nova.console.websocketproxy [-]   - Listen on 0.0.0.0:6080
2020-11-13 03:22:36.132 1240 INFO nova.console.websocketproxy [-]   - Flash security policy server
2020-11-13 03:22:36.132 1240 INFO nova.console.websocketproxy [-]   - Web server (no directory listings). Web root: /usr/share/novnc
2020-11-13 03:22:36.132 1240 INFO nova.console.websocketproxy [-]   - No SSL/TLS support (no cert file)
2020-11-13 03:22:36.133 1240 INFO nova.console.websocketproxy [-]   - proxying from 0.0.0.0:6080 to None:None
2020-11-13 03:38:17.145 5022 INFO nova.console.websocketproxy [-] 10.0.0.77 - - [13/Nov/2020 03:38:17] code 404, message File not found
2020-11-13 03:38:17.366 5024 INFO nova.console.websocketproxy [-] 10.0.0.77 - - [13/Nov/2020 03:38:17] 10.0.0.77: Plain non-SSL (ws://) WebSocket connection
2020-11-13 03:38:17.368 5024 INFO nova.console.websocketproxy [-] 10.0.0.77 - - [13/Nov/2020 03:38:17] 10.0.0.77: Version hybi-13, base64: 'False'
2020-11-13 03:38:17.368 5024 INFO nova.console.websocketproxy [-] 10.0.0.77 - - [13/Nov/2020 03:38:17] 10.0.0.77: Path: '/?token=b7454700-a95a-4596-b6a4-b51db45b1769'
2020-11-13 03:38:17.678 5024 INFO nova.console.websocketproxy [req-67099c31-6b34-4a3c-9f88-45a1ca30ad41 - - - - -]   3: connect info: ConsoleAuthToken(access_url_base='http://10.0.0.10:6080/vnc_auto.html',console_type='novnc',created_at=2020-11-13T03:37:50Z,host='comp1.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal',id=5,instance_uuid=3f2d9390-06c9-47b5-aa26-7f6a0836b1f6,internal_access_path=None,port=5900,token='***',updated_at=None)
2020-11-13 03:38:17.679 5024 INFO nova.console.websocketproxy [req-67099c31-6b34-4a3c-9f88-45a1ca30ad41 - - - - -]   3: connecting to: comp1.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:5900
2020-11-13 03:38:17.686 5024 INFO nova.console.websocketproxy [req-67099c31-6b34-4a3c-9f88-45a1ca30ad41 - - - - -] handler exception: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
2020-11-13 03:39:11.898 5023 INFO nova.console.websocketproxy [-] handler exception: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

Cause : **comp1.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal** was **NOT written** in /etc/hosts

Solve : add alias in hosts

> ```
>   3: connect info: ConsoleAuthToken(access_url_base='http://10.0.0.10:6080/vnc_auto.html'
>   3: connecting to: comp1.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:5900
>  handler exception: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
> ```

BTW, I don't understand why vncproxy trying to connect by hostname from IP-address, suddenly. :p

Answer (score 0):

Start the novnc from terminal with command `vncserver`. Later, refresh the browser.